# return TCPDF after server post ajax issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tcpdf

I am trying to return a tcpdf after validating a form. If there is an error in validation the php file returns an error msg. If the validation succeeds I want to return the PDF.  Trouble is that when the pdf is returned it is not displayed as a PDF just garbage text. What change do I need to make in my code?

Here is my ajax submit code:

```
    function postForm() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');
    /* Get from elements values */
    var values = $("#matchReportForm").serialize()
    ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
            url: "mReport.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#result').html('<img src="images/indicator.gif" alt="loading..." />');
                    $('#btnGo').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("#txtSecurity").focus();
                }
        });

     ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          // show successfully for submit message
          $("#result").html(response);
          $('#btnGo').removeAttr("disabled");
     });

     /* On failure of request this function will be called  */
     ajaxRequest.fail(function (){
       // show error
       $("#result").html(response);
       $('#btnGo').removeAttr("disabled");
     });

    }
```

In my PHP file I either echo an error msg or return the pdf:

```
    $pdf->writeHTML($report, true, false, true, false, '');

    $pdf->Output('match_report.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Well, you cannot simply inject a PDF payload into a html element. How should the server know that this is a PDF document and how to display it? You treat it just like a string, or html markup. That cannot work.

Comment: That's not very helpful, Sorry I should have mentioned that I want the pdf to open if it is returned.  I am only wanting the error msg to be displayed in the div not the pdf.  So I need to check whether the response is html or binary then either show the msg in the div or open the pdf itself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't show directly a PDF into a div for the obvious reason that it's not HTML. But you can embed it in your page using this:

```
function postForm() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');
    /* Get from elements values */
    var values = $("#matchReportForm").serialize()
    ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
        url: "mReport.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#result').html('<img src="images/indicator.gif" alt="loading..." />');
            $('#btnGo').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#txtSecurity").focus();
        }
    });

    ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // show successfully for submit message
        var pdf = $.base64.decode($.trim(response));
        $("#result").html('<embed width=100% height=100% type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + escape(pdf) + '"></embed>');
        $('#btnGo').removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    /* On failure of request this function will be called  */
    ajaxRequest.fail(function (){
        // show error
        $("#result").html(response);
        $('#btnGo').removeAttr("disabled");
    });
}
```

Like base64 data image you can include a PDF in your page as a binary stream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I only want to show the error msg in the div, if it returns a pdf then I'm wanting the pdf to just open not embed it in the div. How can I do that?

Comment: sry i try it, but fail,, in $.base64